# MultiColumns get lost when indexing and re-indexing

Tags: python, pandas

Create some data

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['what', 'why'], ['me', 'you']])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
df.loc[0, :] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What do we have?

```
In[8]: df
Out[8]: 
  what     why    
    me you  me you
0    1   2   3   4
```

Set one (or more) columns as index:

```
In[11]: df.set_index(('what', 'me'))
Out[11]: 
           what why    
            you  me you
(what, me)             
1             2   3   4
```

Let's reset that index:

```
In[12]: df.set_index(('what', 'me')).reset_index()
Out[12]: 
  (what, me) what why    
              you  me you
0          1    2   3   4
```

And in particular,

```
In[13]: df.set_index(('what', 'me')).reset_index().columns
Out[13]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['what', 'why', ('what', 'me')], ['me', 'you', '']],
           labels=[[2, 0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Is there any way to use these (multi) columns as indices without losing the column structure?